# mongodb-C# - attempt to read past the end of the stream?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm relatively new to mongodb as well as database engineering as a whole. I've been looking over this same problem for a solid 2 days now, I've looked all over the web for this problem and have had absolutely 0 luck on a solution.

Basically I'm creating a game in unity and to get what I require I decided to hit the books on creating databases, which so far so good until I get this error when testing out the code

EndOfStreamException: attempt to read past the end of the stream

Here is the block of code that helps it run, though I'm just assuming, I don't think it is the code, it seems more or less something to do with the database just judging by the multiple debugging outputs and changes I have created until I called it quits and decided to ask for help.

```
private const string username = "Insert Username here";
private const string password = "Insert Password here";
private const string MONGO_URL = "mongodb://" + username + ":" + password + " @clusterName-shard-00-02-xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017";
private const string DATABASE_NAME = "test";
private MongoClient client;
private MongoServer server;

private MongoDatabase database;
private MongoCollection accounts;
public void Init()
{
    client = new MongoClient(MONGO_URL);
    server = client.GetServer();
    database = server.GetDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    accounts = database.GetCollection("accounts");
}

public bool InsertAccount(string username, string password, string email)
{
    Model_Account newAccount = new Model_Account();
    newAccount.userName = username;
    newAccount.password = password;
    newAccount.email = email;
    Debug.Log(newAccount.userName);
    Debug.Log(accounts);
    accounts.Insert(newAccount); //Where the error happens.
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I have a insertaccount function that at the moment is called on Start(). Model_Account for the record is only holding values that will be added to the database, doesn't hold anything but that.  I'm really at a loss on what to do with this error so if someone could help with this I'd be grateful.

Edit: The error happens on accounts.Insert(newAccount) seen above

Comment: Where (in which line) does the error occur? Where is _Start()_? When is Init() called?

Comment: Must've forgotten to include that. The error occurs on accounts.Insert() in the InsertAccount function. void Start() is on my Server class which then calls the InsertAccount(). Init() is also called on Start() within the Server class.

Comment: Are you using the most recent MongoDB release and the most recent release of whichever MongoDB driver you are using?

Comment: Yes I do believe so, assuming 4.2.0 is the correct version in which I just double checked on the version in command prompt.

Comment: Oh and the driver is also up to date, forgot to mention that.

Comment: I suspect that you should be using SSL/TLS.  That URL looks like Atlas, which definitely does require it, and if you connect without it, the Atlas node will simply close the connection, leaving your app wondering why it didn't receive the rest of the handshake.  There should be a option in Atlas for it to give you a connection string to copy paste into your app configuration.